# Django query isn't returning id value as an integer

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys

I'm pulling a primary key from the db table *article* and trying to save it as a foreign key into the db table *comment*. I receive the **error**:
*int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'*

I have tried casting *article_id* as an `int(article_id)` but it returns the same error. I have tried pulling the value into a list but then it returns a list error. I have printed the value of the query *article_id* and returns `[{'id': 1L}]` in the terminal, the first article in the db.

This method of inserting a foreign key has worked when updating a record, but now isn't when creating one. **How can I insert a foreign key?**

I'm using Python 2.7 and django 1.9

```
if request.POST.get("ComentForm") is not None:       
    if InsertComent.is_valid():

        article_id = Article.objects.filter(title = Slug).filter(pub_date = aTimestamp).values("id")
        article_id = article_id
        user_id = request.user.id

        p=Comment(comment=InsertComent.cleaned_data['comment'], article_id=article_id, user_id=user_id)
        p.save()

        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                            "Thanks for commenting!", extra_tags="ComentForm"                                    
                            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Article',  kwargs={'aTimestamp':aTimestamp,'aSlug':aSlug}))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your `filter()` call with `get()`:

```
article_id = Article.objects.get(title=Slug, pub_date= aTimestamp).pk
```

The `filter()` method returns a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/): a list of objects matching your criteria. To get only one object (and you mean so, right?) you should call `get()`.

More than that, the `get()` will return a `Model` [instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/), and you seem to need only it's primary key. So that's what the code above basically does.

Comment: Thank you this works, someone ought to put an example into the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

Comment: I bet SO answers often rank better than official docs in Google, so that's not necessarily a problem. Please consider marking this answer as accepted if it works for you.